# Ecuacion dinamica C#

Tags: c#

buen día!

Me pidieron hacer un API que se va a llamar sola cada cierto tiempo. El API debe de actualizar unos valores alojados en una base de datos, el problema es que el API debe de recibir como parámetro una ecuación y esta ecuación va a estar cambiando cada cierto tiempo, por ejemplo:

Esta semana la ecuación para actualizar los valores es; (A + B) * X

La siguiente semana la ecuación puede ser (A - B) * X

Y tal vez al siguiente mes esta sea (2A - B) + X + B

No lose puede se cualquier ecuación lo que siempre sera constante seran los valores de A y B por constantes me refiero a que siempre van a estar presentes en la ecuacion

la ecuación la tomaría de la BD como un String y la manipularía en el codigo

¿Alguna forma de resolver este problema?

Buscando en internet me encontré con el siguiente código:

```
Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));

dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "javascript";

var res = obj.Eval("a=3; 2*a+32-Math.sin(6)");
```

Comment: Como se debe consumir esa API, sera una blilioteca con ese metodo implementado o se llamara mediante una peticion http, o.....